# gameswf can't load swf file under 64 bit ios

Tags: ios, 64-bit, flash

I'm using [gameswf](http://tulrich.com/geekstuff/gameswf.html) to display swf content in my ios app. but if I compile for 64 bit architecture I keep getting error at this line

```
assert(e->is_tombstone() || ! (e->first == key));   // keys are equal, but hash differs!
```

in file `base/container.h` line 1230.

If I only compile for 32 bit architecture, things work fine. Have you faced this problem before?

Answer (score 0):

in `base/container.h` struct entry constructor:replace `int hash_value` with `size_t hash_value`